# How do you make a *.rtf file to be displayed in an UTF-8 encoding on a JContentPane?

Tags: java, swing, character-encoding, rtf, arabic

I'm struggling to display an Arabic rtf in a JEditorPane. It shows the wrong characters probably because it's the wrong encoding and I have no idea on how to fix it.

Can I get some help? Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
                textPane.setEditorKit(new AdvancedRTFEditorKit());
                textPane.setBackground( Color.white );
                try {
                    BufferedReader fi = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(
                                          new FileInputStream("C:/test - Copy.rtf"), "UTF-8"));



                    rtf.read( fi, textPane.getDocument(), 0 );



                    System.out.println(textPane.getDocument());
                    System.out.println(rtf.toString());

                    } 
                catch( FileNotFoundException e )
                {
                System.out.println( "File not found" );
                }
                catch( IOException e )
                {
                System.out.println( "I/O error" );
                }
                catch( BadLocationException e )
                {
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you define the variable `rtf`?

Comment: First display it with `setContentType("text/plain")` (that is without EditorKit). Now you can look, whether the encoding of the file is UTF-8 and whether the selected font does handle arabic.

Comment: rtf is declared as "public static AdvancedRTFEditorKit rtf = new AdvancedRTFEditorKit();"

It is in fact encoded in UTF-8. It doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/test - Copy.rtf"), "UTF-8")
```

You're assuming that your .rtf file is encoded as UTF-8.  If your results look wrong, then the file is probably not UTF-8.  If it's Arabic, then the actual charset is probably ISO-8859-6 or Windows-1256.  If you open that file in a text editor, it should be able to tell you what the character encoding is.  Once you know that you can just use:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/test - Copy.rtf"), "Actual Charset Name")
```

Comment: Looks like it's UTF-8. I just made sure.
I've tried changing it anyway. It doesn't seem to have any effect. The same empty square remain instead of the characters ([][][])